# Sample size using perf record when executing same program at the same sampling frequency but with different events

Tags: linux, perf

When executing perf record command on the same program with the same sampling frequency but with different events.

Should not the sample size be almost equal regardless of what event is counted for?

I'm executing a workload (execution time = 65ms) with same sampling frequency. When counting for cycles event, sample size is almost 1000 samples but when counting for cache misses event sample size is almost 150 samples! Why is this? Should not sample size be equal if the workload and sampling frequency is the same?

Answer (score 2):

If you request a specific frequency (# of samples per second), the kernel will try to find a sampling period (# of events between samples) to achieve the requested frequency. This doesn't always work, especially for short workloads and events with dynamic rates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the difference is huge, I mean 1000 samples compared to 150 samples. does this indicate that perf might not be suitable for short executing workloads?

Comment: It means that you cannot use `perf record` to record time-equidistant samples of certain HW events. This effect is worse for short workloads.

Comment: @user3527764 Maybe you actually have an XY problem here and you didn't actually want to know *"why is this?"* but rather *"how can I answer a certain question with perf"*. Unfortunately the latter is not included in the question, so I can't answer it.

Comment: @zultan would you clarify what do you mean by "certain HW events"? why is it event specific? one of the factors is the high sampling frequency which introduces overhead as number of interrupts will increase. Would you explain why is it related to specific HW events?

Comment: @user3527764: The `cycles` event triggers a *lot* more total times than even `L1-dcache-load-misses`.  Most cycles don't trigger a new cache miss.  It's not surprising that `perf` has a hard time finding a counter setting that will make the cache-miss even trigger as often as the `cycles` event, especially if your workload doesn't generate a huge amount of cache misses.  e.g. if I `perf stat` something like `python -c exit`, I get 39M cycles, but only 267k `cache-misses` (a similar number to `LLC-loads`, and ~4x lower than the 1M `L1-dcache-load-misses`).  Caches work, i.e. hit often!

Comment: @user3527764 *"why is it related to specific HW events?"* this is this depends on how the rate of the event (# / second) varies over time for a given workload. *ref-cycles* are rather stable (unless C states), *instructions* will vary a bit, *mem-loads* will depend highly on the workload.

Comment: I was expecting almost equal sample size regardless of what event perf is counting for because I thought that perf will report zero counter value for a sample period when an event has not occurred.